# What is more comfortable to work with Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been working with VS 2010 for a while. Please tell me does the 2012 has some new option which makes it more comfortable to work with. Like code formating from Eclipse or better resolving problems? Does the VS 2012 will open the VS2010 project?

Comment: If you feel VS 20xx is inadequate, checkout ReSharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2012 opens projects from VS2010, but only in this direction. If You build solution in VS2012 You will not be able to open it in VS2010 anymore.

Comment: Those nerds always close questions. Thank you for the answer : )

Comment: @Robert: The one valid part of your question (at the end) was buried by the subjective part, and almost no-one noticed it.

Comment: @SLaks It is enough to look at your avatar, then on my previous comment

Comment: That is totally incorrect!  In fact this is the FIRST studio release in history where Studio 2010 can in fact open a project that has been converted to 2012.  Microsoft should be applauded for getting this right this time.